# Not receiving kABDatabaseChangedExternallyNotification upon disabling syncing contacts from Facebook account with the ABAddressBook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, abaddressbook

Normally, when contacts are added to or removed from the shared address book, the kABDatabaseChangedExternallyNotification notification is posted.  However, when one disables automatically pulling Facebook contacts into the address book, this notification is not posted.  Is there a work-around for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the developer preview of Facebook account integration under 10.8.1 but has been resolved with the official addition of Facebook account integration in 10.8.2.